# The argument type 'Icon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. I have Expandable List in my app. I'm having problem with assigning icon to Expandable List's header. Title assigning well. I'm using this to require needed data:

```
class ExpandableListItem {
  bool isExpanded;
  final String header;
  final String body;
  final Icon icon; // icon problem

  ExpandableListItem(
      {this.isExpanded: false,
      required this.header,
      required this.body,
      required this.icon});
}
```

After that i pass needed parameters like this:

```
ExpandableListItem(
     header: 'Факультеты',
     body: 'news',
     icon: Icon(
       Icons.ac_unit,
       color: Colors.red,
     ),
   ),
```

And when i used it to assign it to header i use this:

```
return Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              item.icon
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 8),
                            Text(
                              item.header,
                              style: MainTheme.lightTheme.textTheme.headline2,
                            )
                          ],
                        );
```

And here is the problem. I'm having the error as

> "The argument type 'Icon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData?'". How can i fix this error?

Comment: ``item.icon`` is already a type of ``Icon``

Comment: ? I didn't get it

Comment: use it directly without the Icon widget, pass it as: ``item.icon`` in the row widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the problem is that, in the `ExpandableListItem class`, you are having a field of type `Icon` and it's already an **Icon widget**. Hence in your Row widget, you **don't** need to add/create a new Icon widget.

Instead, you can directly use item.icon as an Icon widget.

```
return Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                          item.icon
                        ,
                        SizedBox(width: 8),
                        Text(
                          item.header,
                          style: MainTheme.lightTheme.textTheme.headline2,
                        )
                      ],
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ExpandableListItem {
  bool isExpanded;
  final String header;
  final String body;
  final Widget icon; 
}
```

```
ExpandableListItem(
     header: 'Факультеты',
     body: 'news',
     icon: Icon(
       Icons.ac_unit,
       color: Colors.red,
     ),
   ),
```

```
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    item.icon,
    SizedBox(width: 8),
    Text(
      item.header,
      style: MainTheme.lightTheme.textTheme.headline2,
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: what if he has to pass custom color and size? This is totally not recommended !!

Comment: @OMiShah so instead of Icon as a dataType better make it ```final Widget icon```

Comment: No need to change it the widget type. Just use the item.icon directly in the row widget without wrapping the item.icon with the icon widget.